# How to set a date in cq through xml?

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, aem

I am reading contents of one XML file into another using XSLT, such that the resultant XSLT must be in the XML format of an adobe CQ format, allowing me to import the .zip file.

When I read a date, it is in the exact format as I need it, however I am not able to set it as {Date} into CQ. How can I do so?

Comment: Showing your code would be the first step - together with an input XML, the current output and the expected output. Thanks!

Comment: Please indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved. you need to write a java method that reads your xslt:value-of select=method(variablefromsource) "and converts into required format . Then use {date}

Comment: The answer is just as cryptic as the question.